# React map method Render Input dynamically change value separate fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I am  got a loop data Array that contains more than 100 data and I am used  map method  to render it that are already defined the user can update only for the specific field have id and unique id  I now need to be able to edit/submit them uniquely separate fields.All fields should be some default.
At the moment, I haven't figured out how to differentiate them onChange causing the state to be the same on ALL fields.
I need each field to update separately with its unique data and I am using react hooks
Input Forms, rendered by the map. These are the forms I want unique update fields.

Please Give Any Idea that will helpful to implement or suggestion how to approach this I am new to react please help us

Thanks for Help

codesandoxLink:https://codesandbox.io/s/react-week-date-view-r3mvj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code changed to update particular field in loop. if you want to other field to update you can follow the same.

pass ID and event to function

```
<input
    name="roomRent"
    type="text"
    value={roomData.room}
    className={classes.input}
    onChange={(e) => handleroom(e, i)}
 />
```

function to update particulat field value

```
  const handleroom = (e, id) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setRooms((room) =>
      room?.map((list, index) =>
        index === id ? { ...list, room: value } : list
      )
    );
  };
```

Improved code

```
export default function RoomListView() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [roomes, setRooms] = useState([...rooms]);

  const handleroom = (e, id) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setRooms((room) =>
      room?.map((list, index) =>
        index === id ? { ...list, room: value } : list
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper} variant="outlined" elevation={0}>
          <div className={classes.layout}>
            <div className={classes.main1}>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item sm={3}>
                  <div className={classes.roomType}>
                    <h4 className={classes.roomTypeContent}>Room Rate</h4>
                  </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={9}>
                  <div className={classes.Roomcalendar}>
                    {roomes.map((roomData, i) => {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <div className={classes.Roomview}>
                            <div
                              key={roomData.id}
                              className={classes.roomavailable}
                            >
                              <input
                                name="roomRent"
                                type="text"
                                value={roomData.room}
                                className={classes.input}
                                onChange={(e) => handleroom(e, i)}
                              />
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.roomSold}>
                              <p>{roomData.sold} Sold</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Live working code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-week-date-view-forked-72pw3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-week-date-view-forked-vnrvt?file=/src/App.js) a working solution (I edited your codesandbox).
Basically what I have done is:

1. initialize `roomRent` with `rooms`:

   ```
    const [roomRent, setRoomRent] = useState(rooms);
   ```
2. use `map` on roomRent:

   ```
    roomRent.map((roomData) => {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <div className={classes.Roomview}>
                            <div
                              key={roomData.id}
                              className={classes.roomavailable}
                            >
                              <input
                                name="roomRent"
                                type="text"
                                value={roomData.room}
                                className={classes.input}
                                onChange={(e) => handleroom(e, roomData.id)}
                              />
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.roomSold}>
                              <p>{roomData.sold} Sold</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </>
                      );
                    })
   ```

Note that now `handleroom` has 2 inputs: `e` and `roomData.id`;

3. changed `handleroom` function in this way:

   ```
    const handleroom = (e, id) => {
        var result = [...roomRent]; //<- copy roomRent into result
        result = result.map((x) => { //<- use map on result to find element to update using id
          if (x.id === id) x.room = e.target.value;
          return x;
        });
        setRoomRent(result); //<- update roomRent with value edited
      };
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I am learned it and try to implement it